# Take data for each day in tsrange

Tags: postgresql

Assuming a have table like

```
+----------------------------+-----+-----------+
+           tsrange          + id  + anyvalues +
+----------------------------------------------+
+["2019-09-20","2019-09-25") +  1  +    ...    +
+["2019-09-01","2019-09-23") +  2  +    ...    +
+["2019-09-15","2019-09-22") +  3  +    ...    +
+            ...             + ... +    ...    +
+----------------------------+-----+-----------+
```

Is it possible to get data state for each day from 2019-09-01 till 2019-09-25?
I just have no idea what could be query or probably any function exists for it purpose.

So in output i'd like to get 25 raws with values for each id (if it exists for it)

Comment: You cannot know more than the contents of the rows, if one row spans from the 20th to the 25th then that's all accuracy you have. I suppose you could do an average, via `generate_series()`, the minimum and maximum can be fetched with `lower()` and `upper()` but I do feel a little uneasy suggesting you fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this?  The expected output would help determine if this is correct:

```
select d, count(id)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
RIGHT JOIN generate_series('2019-09-01'::timestamp, '2019-09-25'::timestamp, interval '1 day') AS g(d) on tsrange @> d
group by d order by 1;
          d          | count
---------------------+-------
 2019-09-01 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-02 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-03 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-04 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-05 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-06 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-07 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-08 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-09 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-10 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-11 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-12 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-13 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-14 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-15 00:00:00 |     2
 2019-09-16 00:00:00 |     2
 2019-09-17 00:00:00 |     2
 2019-09-18 00:00:00 |     2
 2019-09-19 00:00:00 |     2
 2019-09-20 00:00:00 |     3
 2019-09-21 00:00:00 |     3
 2019-09-22 00:00:00 |     2
 2019-09-23 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-24 00:00:00 |     1
 2019-09-25 00:00:00 |     0
(25 rows)
```

Comment: it's almost what i need, but as a result i'd like to get 25 rows which in the following format
date | count of all records grouped by id
in my data sample for 2019-09-23 date  it would be
2019-09-23 | 2 (because id 1 and 3 has this date)

Comment: I edited to what I think you mean: grouped by date, not id (otherwise there would be no way to get 25 rows for 25 days).  Also, only id 1 has a value on 2019-09-23.  id 2 is specifically excluded from this date in your sample data.

Comment: seems like this is exactly what I was looking for! I appreciate you. Btw why right join?

Comment: and one more little question. Is it possible to return 0 in count table in case if there are nothing? for example if my search would started from 2019-08-15 where i have no data for this date

Comment: Yes, just expand the range and it will return 0.  In fact, it's already returning 0 for the last day because there's no data for that day.  That's the point of the right outer join.